# What is the point of encrypting user passwords on the frontend?

Tags: security, encryption, https, rsa, api-design

I'm working with an API that requires the user's password to be encrypted with the server's public key before sending to the server. If the whole request, including username/password/etc. is being sent through HTTPS, isn't the password encryption redundant?

Comment: Please share more details. Is the encrypted payload just the password, or does it include other things (maybe a session ID or ??).

Comment: Of note is that this doesn't protect against a replay attack. If someone were able to look inside the HTTPS (see Rob's answer) they could use the same password ciphertext. Even Rob's KDF technique doesn't solve this (unless the server supplied a single use salt for use with this particular API call).

Comment: @ChrisJohnson the payload has username, password, grant type (password), and the client id (i.e. mobile app, website, etc), but password is the only part of the payload that is encrypted. The rest is plaintext json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the server architecture, this kind of encryption can be helpful. For example, the TLS (HTTPS) connection may be terminated (decrypted) at the perimeter of the network in order to simplify load balancing or to scan the stream for malicious packets. Separately encrypting the password protects the password even from the edge servers, so an attacker who is able to compromise one of those still cannot gain access to the password.

Personally I stretch (i.e. PBDKF2) passwords before sending them. This ensures that the raw password is never seen by the server at all. But even in that configuration, an extra layer of encryption for the hash could be useful when the TLS stream is decrypted early.